# Missing HTML Attribute Value With Spaces from jQuery

Tags: html, jquery

I have some jQuery where I am appending text where some of their attributes take some js variables.

```
<script>
var className = "COS 102";
var teacher = "Bob Teacher";

$("#classesDiv").append("<div className="+className+" teacher="+teacher+" class='class'></div>");
</script>
```

The issue I am having is that when I pass these variables into the element it comes out looking like `className="COS"`, without the 102 after.

Does anybody know why this is happening?

Comment: `COS 102` is not a valid class name, that's a class name of `COS` and an invalid classname `102`, [refer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/448981/what-characters-are-valid-in-css-class-selectors) for a better explination

Comment: @BrettSantore it's not *className* as an HTML class, but a custom attribute *className* as in a school class.

Comment: Ah, sorry about that, should have read more thoroughly, saw `className` and reacted.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Because you don't have quotes around the attribute values.

Your code is going to append:

`<div className=COS 102 ...`

when it should append

`<div className='COS 102' ...`

This should work:

```
<script>
var className = "COS 102";
var teacher = "Bob Teacher";

$("#classesDiv").append("<div className='"+className+"' teacher='"+teacher+"' class='class'></div>");
</script>
```

Comment: Hahaha! Thanks! I can't believe I missed this.

Answer (score 4):

Think about the string you're appending:

```
<div className=COS 102 teacher=Bob Teacher class='class'></div>
```

Since those attribute values aren't quoted, `102` and `Teacher` are seen as separate, value-less attributes.  You'll want to get:

```
<div className='COS 102' teacher='Bob Teacher' class='class'></div>
```

by quoting:

```
$("#classesDiv").append("<div className='" + className + "' teacher='" + teacher + "' class='class'></div>");
```

Or, to be more jQuery-ish about it:

```
$('<div>').
  attr({
    'className' : className,
    'teacher' : teacher
  }).
  appendTo($('#classesDiv'));
```

An advantage to the last approach: it works even if `teacher` or `className` *contain* quotes (either single or double), or other characters that are meaningful to HTML.

Comment: He's not trying to add a class, but an attribute *className*.

Answer (score 2):

It's happening because you're constructing an element by joining strings together. As you can see, this approach is fragile. Construct the element by passing an object to jQuery's `$` function:

```
var className = 'COS 102';
var teacher = 'Bob Teacher';

$('<div>', {
    className: className,
    teacher: teacher,
    'class': 'class'
}).appendTo('#classesDiv');
```

Also, custom attributes like `className` and `teacher` are not valid HTML. You must prefix them with `data-`:

```
$('<div>', {
    'data-className': className,
    'data-teacher': teacher,
    'class': 'class'
})
```